# Acessar uma lista dentro de uma lista em react jsx

Tags: javascript, react, axios, jsx

Olá, eu sou um novato em React e estou fazendo uma requisição via axios. Essa requisição me retorna o seguinte JSON: 
[image: Retorno API]

depois de receber essa lista eu faço um `.map` na lista e ele me retorna o seguinte:
[image: Retorno .map]

O que eu quero é pegar a `lista_area_negocio` e a `lista_depto`. Porém não sei como.

Esses são alguns trechos do meu código:

```
  componentDidMount() {
axios.get(API_ListaEmpresa)
  .then(response => {
    this.setState({ listaEmpresa: response.data });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  })
```

Aqui eu faço a lista de empresas, essa fica certinho o problema é pegar a lista de departamentos e área de negócios.

```
{/* Empresa */}
          <div className="input-group mb-3">
            <div className="input-group-prepend">
              <label className="input-group-text" htmlFor="empresa">Empresa: </label>
            </div>
            <select value={this.state.company} className="form-control" id="empresa" required="required" onChange={this.handleCompanyChange}>
              <option value={0} >Escolha...</option>
              {this.state.listaEmpresa.map(function (empresa) {
                return (<option key={empresa.ax_cod_empresa} value={empresa.ax_cod_empresa}>{empresa.ax_desc_empresa}</option>);
              })
              }
            </select>
          </div>
              {
              console.log(this.state.listaEmpresa)
              }
```

Essa seria a lista de departamentos que não consigo pegar.

```
{/* Departamento */}
          <div className="input-group mb-3">
            <div className="input-group-prepend">
              <label className="input-group-text" htmlFor="departamento">Departamento: </label>
            </div>
            {
              this.state.company !== 0
                ? <select className="form-control" id="departamento" required="required" onChange={this.handleDepartmentChange}>
                  <option value={0}>Escolha...</option>
                  {this.state.listaEmpresa.map(function (departamento) {
                    return (console.log(departamento), <option key={departamento.lista_depto.ax_cod_dept} value={departamento.lista_depto.ax_cod_dept}>{departamento.lista_depto.ax_desc_dept}</option>);
                  })
                  }
                </select>
                : <select className="form-control" id="departamento" required="required" disabled><option value={0}>Selecione uma empresa</option></select>
            }
          </div>
```

Como faço para separar a lista de departamentos e de área de negócios? Eu também quero conseguir pegar os dados da `lista_depto` e `lista_area_negocio`.

**Obs.: A `lista_depto` e `lista_area_negocio` dependem da lista empresa, ou seja eu só posso mostrar ao usuário a `lista_depto` e `lista_area_negocio` correspondente a empresa que ele solicitou.**

Comment: Bem vindo ao site, prefira colocar o seu código mesmo ao invés de imagem. Pois fica mais fácil de replicarmos e formular uma resposta, com imagem teriamos que digitar tudo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gabriel você precisa fazer um map dentro de outro apenas isso, vc já está com os dados na mão só percorrer !
Criei uma lista para vc ver como é simples !!

```
var lista = [{

"ax_cnpj" :223132123,
"lista_departamento":[{
    "ax_desc_dept": "Pesquisa e Desenvolvimento"


}]
```

}];

------------------------------------- Aqui acessando a lista --------------------

```
lista.map(
(lista) => {
    lista.lista_departamento.map(
    (departamento) => console.log(departamento.ax_desc_dept)
    )
})
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poderia me dizer como eu faria isso? Eu estou tentando mas não estou conseguindo.

Comment: Olha este exemplo que te mandei ai e segue a mesma lógica, pois no exemplo usei a mesma estrutura que vc usou apenas não coloquei todos os campos.

Comment: Primeiro percorre a lista de empresas com um map ok, depois pega a lista de departamentos e percorre com outro map.                                          
 Aqui  vc tem que mudar isto lá no segundo map this.state.listaEmpresa.lista_dept.map()